How to log in separate users on different "screens" in Debian?
With Debian 12 (Bookworm) and Gnome I can use ctrl-alt-left/right to slide between screens.
I use my computer with multiple usernames, one for each project or task.
Switching users is currently cumbersome, as it requires a few clicks and re-typing the password.
Is there a way that I could log-in multiple users and just ctrl-alt-left-right between them?  (Or some similar low-friction way of having multiple user-desktops active without having to retype the passwords every few minutes?)

Is not using different users for the same individual on the same machine an option? It seems like you are making things very complicated for yourself for no real benefit. Are you sure it is worth the extra effort to use separate accounts like this? You might want to ask a new question, explaining what benefits you get from the multiple users, and asking how to get those benefits. There might be a simpler, better way to do what you want.

Yes, this very much sounds like you want some kind of isolation for specific tasks, or something similar, which your proposed setup might not even give you any better than an easier solution. Would be pretty cool if you could just add information on what the ideal is that you're following here! Why do you want to have that setup you describe? Maybe there's a really simple solution to that!

When you open multiple sessions in parallel, each session gets its own virtual terminal. You can switch between them using CtrlAltFn; …F1 should take you to the user selection screen, F2 to the first logged-in user, etc.
Switching in this way won’t immediately lock the session you’re leaving; it will lock when the lock timeout is reached.

I hadn't discovered this because on my (perfectly standard) Debian 12 installation ctrl-alt-F1 is the selection screen, ...F2 is the first user, ...F3 is a text-mode shell login and ...F4 is the second logged-in user.
